# Shortening lengthy jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I'm relatively new to Javascript and jQuery, the latter I only started learning yesterday as it happens! So please be gentle :)

Basically, I'm building a website that loads images into a div (class="mapDisplay") and text into another div (class="blogText) based on the dropdown box (id="region") selection. This function is called "onchange" on the "region" dropdown box. All the code functions correctly but it just seems excessively long. The code to load the image into the 'mapDisplay' element is identical for each case of the switch statement - the only thing that changes is the 'src'. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to condense it?

Here is a sample of two of the cases...

```
function displayMap(region){
var selectedRegion = document.getElementById("region").value;
switch(selectedRegion){
        case "":
            removeCurrentMap();
        break;
        case "Nagrand":
            $(".blogText").fadeOut("slow");
            $(".mapDisplay").fadeOut("slow",
            function(){
                $(".mapDisplay").empty();
                $(".mapDisplay").append("<img src='mapImages/outland/nagrand.jpg' height='100%' width='100%' style='margin-top:10px'>");
                $(".blogText").load("blogText/outland/nagrand.txt");
                $(".mapDisplay").fadeIn("slow");
                $(".blogText").fadeIn("slow");
            });
        break;
        case "Zangarmarsh":
            $(".blogText").fadeOut("slow");
            $(".mapDisplay").fadeOut("slow",
            function(){
                $(".mapDisplay").empty();
                $(".mapDisplay").append("<img src='mapImages/outland/zangar.jpg' height='100%' width='100%' style='margin-top:10px'>");
                $(".blogText").load("blogText/outland/zangar.txt");
                $(".mapDisplay").fadeIn("slow");
                $(".blogText").fadeIn("slow");
            });
        break; .....etc. etc. etc.
```

Comment: Prepping something for WoD, I see? Let me see if I can help. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I recommend posting the full code on [codereview.se]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what [cr] is! And yes kehrk, sorry about that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another function can make it look a bit better. Try this:

```
function updateDisplay(region) {
    $(".blogText").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".mapDisplay").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(".mapDisplay").empty();
        $(".mapDisplay").append("<img src='mapImages/outland/" + region + ".jpg' height='100%' width='100%' style='margin-top:10px'>");
        $(".blogText").load("blogText/outland/" + region + ".txt");
        $(".mapDisplay").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".blogText").fadeIn("slow");
    });
}

function displayMap(region) {
    var selectedRegion = document.getElementById("region").value;
    switch (selectedRegion) {
        case "":
            removeCurrentMap();
            break;
        case "Nagrand":
            updateDisplay("nagrand");
            break;
        case "Zangarmarsh":
            updateDisplay("zangar");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a switch/case to change one string for another, use a hash/object which would be faster and more compact:

```
values = {Nagrand: 'negrand', Zangarmarsh: 'zangar', etc: ....}
```

Now extract this function:

```
function handleDisplay(arg1){
  $(".blogText").fadeOut("slow");
  $('.mapDisplay').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(".mapDisplay").empty().append("<img src='mapImages/outland/" + arg1 + ".jpg' alt='something for valid markup'>");
    $(".blogText").load("blogText/outland/" + arg1 + ".txt");
    $(".mapDisplay, .blogText").fadeIn("slow");
  });
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if (selectedRegion == '') removeCurrentMap();
else handleDisplay(values[selectedRegion]);
```

If you need more values just add them to the "values" object.

One advice, I've moved the css of the image from javascript to css:

Your css file:

```
.mapDisplay img {
  height: 100%,
  width: 100%,
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate - I've used this idea and it's streamlined the whole process. What's the exact name of the hash/object process so I can read up on it?

Comment: is not a process or anything, it's jus a basic data type of javascript http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp